# Manage a folder and files using Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I've tried searching for a similar question on this issue but couldn't find anything addressing this issue.

I am very new to Chef so might get some terminologies incorrect. Please bear with me.

I have a git repo locally on the chef-server eg. `/var/my-code/`

I'd like to add all the files and folders inside 
`/var/my-code/properties/` to `/app/files/properties/`on the node host machine.

One way I was planning to do it was to create a symlink in the 
`properties/files/default/<symlink>` to `/var/my-code/properties/` but this fails when I run knife upload as the repo is located on the chef-server not the workstation. I get this error when I run knife upload.

```
Uploading properties     [0.1.0]
ERROR: The cookbook properties has one or more broken files
ERROR: This is probably caused by broken symlinks in the cookbook directory
ERROR: The broken file(s) are: files/default/properties
```

With `remote_directory` there is (as far as I can see) no option to add a folder path such as `/var/my-code/properties/` as the source. Its expecting the files/folders to be in the /files directory from the cookbook.

Here's my recipe

```
remote_directory '/app/files/properties' do
  source 'properties'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The git repository being on the Chef Server isn't relevant, Chef Server only interacts with clients via its own API.

You probably want something like this:

```
git '/var/my-code' do
  repository 'http://mygitserver/my-code.git'
end

link '/app/files/properties' do
  to '/var/my-code/properties'
end
```